# Increment when element becomes visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, skrollr

I am working with the skrollr plugin.

I have a set of arrows. One points down and the other up. When you click the down arrow it takes you to the next section/chapter of the animation. Right now it works great. But my issues is lets say the user does the following:

He/she scrolls half way through the page(lets say section 5). They then decided to see how much of the animation is left. So they click the next section arrow.

This user will be put to section 2 even though they are at section 5 because I have no way to detect when the user hits each section so I can update the arrow #hrefAnchor.

What I was thinking is adding an interval/ event listener that would detect when the section is visible on the DOM and update the arrows to take you to the previous and next sections.

Does anyone know how I can approach this idea?... and will work in ie >= 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to modify the Skrollr library, something I had done was add:

```
else if(prop === 'javascript') {
    eval(val);
}
```

as an option in `skrollr.setStyle` which allows then for you to add a hook for arbitrary JavaScript code on elements like each section here using `data-XXX="javascript:myFunction();"` and I believe Skrollr will even still interpolate numbers in your arguments for you.

Comment: @Christian4423 In the current version here https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/blob/master/src/skrollr.js it would be line 1418.

Comment: @Christian4423 The only thing to be careful of is that Skrollr may adjust any numbers that appear in the property value. So you'll need to pass strings or such as flags.

Comment: Lol I just passing a number too. But how do I add the `skrollr.setStyle`? is it var            `s=skrollr.init({setStyle: true});`

Comment: @Christian4423 I'm not sure what you mean? `setStyle` is called internally - that's what Skrollr calls after interpreting the `data-` attribute to actually modify the properties of elements. So if you added the code snippet from the answer, and then add a `javascript:` property in a `data-` attribute, it should "just work". I'd start initially with a `console.log` as a PoC.

Comment: Oh I thought it was something I had to turn on. But I just realized what you meant by that... Sorry it is a Monday! Okay well I added that in and my function is not being called. Let me look at it for a second and get back

Comment: They are all firing at once.. Do you know how to prevent this?

Comment: @Christian4423 What `data-` attributes did you add to the sections? Each should only fire when the appropriate threshold is being hit.

Comment: data-17800p="javascript: ai = 6 changeHTMLelement()"

Comment: the only thing that is changing is the ai value and the data-XXXp It is firing before my DOM is fully loaded and causing an error. Should I maybe if I load skrollr after DOM load?

Comment: @Christian4423 I'm not familiar with the `p` suffix but when I added that it did indeed appear to fire on page load. What are the semantics supposed to be? Without the `p` it appears to work as I would expect: http://jsfiddle.net/542u30wL/

Comment: @Christian4423 I was able to find the meaning `p` as percentage. Perhaps then it is indeed related to the loading of the document - perhaps at initialization the viewport height is 0 so any percentage increment would fire. You would need to delay init, avoid percentages, or structure the JS in such a way that calling it that early is not a problem.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I will have to make it more stable. Thanks again for all your help today

Answer (score 2):

If you have control of what gets executed when "next" is clicked, can you check the scroll value at that time to determine which section it is between and switch on that to send them to the appropriate section? Essentially, rather than trying to keep the target current at all times which is wasteful/difficult/error prone, just calculate it when it matters - when the click occurs.

Comment: I wanted to do that originally. But I did not see in the documentation on how to get the scroll position of a specific element to compare to the s.getScrollTop() value.

Comment: @Christian4423 I think you use `relativeToAbsolute` (https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#relativetoabsoluteelement-viewportanchor-elementanchor) something like `relativeToAbsolute(element, 'top', 'top')` would be the scroll position when the top of the element is at the top of the viewport.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan I think the first sentence appropriately answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you give your element a class like `"visible"`, you could select all the visible elements by using jQuery:

```
$(".element.visible:last-of-type").on("click", function() {

});
```

Comment: All elements are already visible. Its a matter of when they hit the DOM when I scroll to it. No click event needed.